# Testing the communication between parent and child view models with Combine

Tags: swift, combine

In order not to have a gigantic view model, I have moved to an approach of a view model with multiple children view models. I want to be able to communicate between parent and child view model and I thought about using Combine's `PassthroughSubject` to get this done.

```
final class PotatoViewModel: PotatoViewModelProtocol {
    private let router: PotatoRouterProtocol
    private let interactor: InteractorProtocol
    private let navigationSubject: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>

    init(router: PotatoRouterProtocol, interactor: InteractorProtocol) {
        let childAViewModel = ChildAViewModel(interactor: interactor.getChildAInteractor())

        let navigationSubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        let childBViewModel = ChildBViewModel(interactor: interactor.getChildBInteractor(),
                                              subject: navigationSubject)

        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.navigationSubject = navigationSubject

        setupBindings()
    }

    private func setupBindings() {
        navigationSubject
            .sink { [weak self] value in
                print("Do something")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }
}
```

I am easily able to test a child view model because I can send a `PassthroughSubject` and check if a value is sent but how do I test the parent considering that the navigationSubject is created in the parent - as it's exclusively used for a child view model and I'm unsure about exposing it in the protocol.

Comment: What are you trying to test about the parent?  Since the subject is private to the parent, it seems that you should be exercising whatever outward-facing functionality the is used to implement and ensure that that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing a PassthroughSubject to the child. Instead the child should expose a Publisher that the parent can `sink` to.

As you already have figured, to test the `ChildBViewModel`, you just sink to its Publisher and poke it.

Testing the `PotatoViewModel` should be exactly the same. It should expose one or more Publishers and to test it, you sink to its Publisher(s) and poke it.

The next step in your architecture evolution will be to realize that these child view models rarely need state. You can write them as a function that accepts one or more Publishers as input and returns a Publisher as output.